# Problemas al cargar una función

Tags: javascript, html5

tengo la siguiente función la cual esta dentro de una carpeta la cual tiene una referencia de la siguiente manera:

```
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        touch: true,
        pauseOnAction: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
    });
  });
</script>
```

Pero sale este error en el inspector de Google Chrome

> TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function[Saber más]

Comment: Asegúrate de que la ruta `js/jquery.flexslider.js` es correcta. Y solo por curiosidad... qué te devuelve `console.log(typeof $('.flexslider').flexslider);`?

Comment: esta bien la ruta de js

Comment: Si la función está dentro de una carpeta según donde la ejecutes la ruta relativa con la que cargas el js de flexslider puede ser errónea. Prueba con una ruta absoluta, por ejemplo https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.1/jquery.flexslider.js

Comment: Es un plugin de jquery, ¿tienes la librería de jquery cargada?